# Como ordenar e classificar strings sem utilizar Collection?

Tags: java, string, classificação

Estou criando um registro de funcionários com alguns campos(nome, e-mail, telefone e salário) em `ArrayList` que são gravados em txt.

Depois que os dados são inseridos no array(antes de passar para o txt) eles precisam ser ordenados pelo nome, que é o primeiro campo da esquerda para a direita.

E é aqui que está o problema, pois não posso usar nenhum método pronto de ordenação tipo sort. Tenho que criar um quicksort.

Já tentei de várias formas e não consegui.
Pensei em tentar com o string compare, mas não sei como ele poderia fazer para classificar por ordem alfabética.

Será que ele vai funcionar? Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Classe Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>(); 



... menu do programa..

case 1:   
   Funcionario func = new Funcionario();
   func.cadastrar(); 
   funcionarios.add(func);
   System.in.read(); 
   System.out.println("\n\nFuncionario cadastrado: " + func.toString());                  
break;
```

Classe cadastrar

```
public void cadastrar()
{
     System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n----- Cadastro de funcionário -----");

     System.out.print("\nInforme o nome: ");
     String nome = ler.nextLine();
     this.setNome(nome);

     System.out.print("\nInforme o e-mail: ");
     String email = ler.nextLine();
     this.setEmail(email);

     boolean valida;
     do
     {
        System.out.print("\nInforme o telefone: ");
        String telefone = ler.nextLine();

       if(telefone.length() != 10)
        {
           System.out.println("Erro!!\nO formato exige 10 dígitos\n");
           valida = false;
        }
        else 
        {
           valida = true;
           this.setTelefone(telefone);
        }
     }while(!valida);

     do
     {
        System.out.print("\nInforme o salário: R$ ");
        float salario = ler.nextFloat();
        if(salario <= 0)
        {
           System.out.println("ERRO!! Valor inválido");
           valida = false;
        }
        else 
        {
           valida = true;
           this.setSalario(salario);
        }
     }while(!valida);
 PrintWriter gravarTxt = new PrintWriter(arquivo);
 gravarTxt.printf("\r\n"+this.nome+" "+this.email+" "+this.telefone+" R$ "+this.salario);
 gravarTxt.flush();
}
```

Comment: Oi Maximiliano, tudo bem? Fica mais fácil de te ajudar se você criar um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrando exatamente onde está seu problema. O método `compare` é útil para comparar ordem lexicográfica sim (ele pode substituir a parte que seria feita com operadores de comparação `>`, `<` no caso de ordenação de tipos como `int`).

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque, Anthony. Corrigido

Comment: Cara da uma olhada nisso, vê se você consegue entender e aplicar no seu código http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377448/how-to-do-sorting-in-array-list-without-using-collections-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = lista.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
        if (lista.get(i).getNome().compareToIgnoreCase(lista.get(j).getNome()) > 0) {

            Pessoa tmp = lista.get(i);
            lista.set(i, lista.get(j));
            lista.set(j, tmp);

        }
    }
}
```

Neste código utilizei dois laços, onde o primeiro percorre os indices do array de forma crescente, e o segundo de forma decrescente até o ponto onde o primeiro se encontra.

O método [`compareToIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) ignora o "case" das palavras e compara a palavra do indice atual com indices posteriores. Sempre que o resultado for maior que 0, significa que a string a direita é anterior a string a esquerda(nosso índice atual), e isso faz com que troque as duas de posição no array.

Essa é uma implementação do [bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9w8sv2)**

**Referência:**  **[How to do sorting in array list without using collections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377448/how-to-do-sorting-in-array-list-without-using-collections-in-java)**

Comment: Funcionou, brother. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [**`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Para isso você precisa criar uma classe que implemente a interface [**`Comparable<T>`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Considerando que você tenha uma lista de funcionários e esta classe tenha os seguintes atributos e métodos:

```
public class Funcionario {

    private final String nome;

    public Funcionario(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Ao implementar **`Comparable`**, você obrigatoriamente precisa sobrescrever o método `compare`. Como você quer ordenar pelo atributo nome, seu comparador pode ficar assim:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FuncionarioComparator implements Comparator<Funcionario> { 

    @Override
    public int compare(Funcionario funcionario1, Funcionario funcionario2) {
        return funcionario1.getNome().compareTo(funcionario2.getNome());
    } 
}
```

Tendo esse comparador, você pode usá-lo no método `sort`:

```
ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
// Populando 'funcionarios'...

Collections.sort(funcionarios, new FuncionarioComparator());
```

#### [Exemplo online.](https://ideone.com/Wbqhpy)

Comment: Ele não pode usar nenhum metodo pronto de ordenação, tem que fazer manualmente, veja a pergunta.

Comment: Infelizmente não dá pra usar o Sort, Renan, Obrigado pela dedicação em criar o código.