# Ordenar Lista de String

Tags: java, arraylist

Alguém sabe como posso ordenar uma lista (`Array List`)de `Strings` que contenha informação alfanuméricos do tipo:

```
"ABC 12"
"A 8"
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(lista);`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ordenar e classificar strings em java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98351/como-ordenar-e-classificar-strings-em-java)

Answer (score 0):

Collections.sort(tuaLista, tuaClasseComparator);

Onde o comparator deve implementar a interface java.util.Comparato
Como usá-la vc pode ver na api, ali explica qual deve ser o retorno do método compare de acordo com o método de comparação que você irá utilizar...